# Is the Dark O(ne) worshiped in Girl Genius?

Tags: girl-genius

In Castle Heterodyne there are instructions engraved in the stairs one should follow before gloating. One of them seems to be appease the Dark O(One?).

[image]

It could simply be rule of funny, but there is a [cathedral](http://girlgenius.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Cathedral) in Mechanicsburg and at least a resemblance of a religion. There are demonic statues in the cathedral and kids are named after [Moloch](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20120817#.WZCcIxXhDDc).

So my question is do people of Mechanisburg worship the Dark One?

Comment: Nah, cathedral is ironical, "technically" Christian.

Comment: Any chance the "O" is about "Other"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.  Probably not... more or less.**

- These stairs are actually the stairs to Lucrezia's secret lab well underneath Castle Heterodyne.  Even the castle wasn't aware what was there, so this is all her stuff.  Presuming that these were reminders she left for herself, she has only ever been shown to consider herself divine, and the reference to the Dark One just another chore on her to-do list.
- Even if you don't buy that, this is Castle Heterodyne, and Mechanicsburg itself didn't even have a Catherdral to worship anyone until the "Prince of Sturmhalten's Big Bet" a while back (yes, a sandwich reference is history here).  Considering Martellus was able to use it to escape Mechanicsburg, this is likely political maneuvering rather than religious harmony, but the point is Mechanicsburg hasn't always had an organized religion, so if the Dark One is worshipped, it's not likely widespread.
- The Red Cathedral itself appears to be built as a mockery of the Notre Dame cathedral, so what religion it pays service to is an open question (it could even be Catholic, for no other reason than the traditional area sense of humor).  There is [at least one](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20120817) example of the church warning of the dangers of militant agnostics.
- Even considering all of the above... this is Mechanicsburg, town of minions and loonies.  Someone probably worships something dire *somewhere*, just not the whole town.